# Pasting object names inside functions

Tags: r

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672009/create-a-loop-to-find-the-best-model-based-on-aic/49672275#49672275) (see data and previous commands).

Starting with a list of models in `mods`, i am now able to find the model with the least AIC (corresponds to the best model):

```
    mods <- lapply(methods, function(m) 
      update(amod.null, correlation = getFunction(m)(1, form = ~ x + y), method="ML"))
    names(mods) <- methods
    list.AIC <- lapply(mods, function(x) AIC(x))
    best.mod <- names(which.min(list.AIC))
```

Now, i need to do some testing on the model, e.g. Tukey between dates. The syntax is very simple, e.g. for `amod.null`

```
library(multcomp)
res <- glht(amod.null, mcp(Date = "Tukey"))
```

**The tricky part is, how can i tell  `glht` to use the model which was put into `best.mod`** (note: this is all happening within a loop). I tried

```
res <- glht(paste("mods$", as.factor(best.mod),sep = "") , mcp(Date = "Tukey"))
```

but to no avail, as glht needs to find a model-object in the first argument.

/edit:
Possibly useful:

```
   names(mods)
[1] "corExp"    "corGaus"   "corLin"    "corRatio"  "corSpher"
```

Comment: Were you aware that you can select list elements by name using `[[`? i.e. `mods[[best.mod]]`?

Comment: No, i wasnt. Seems to run well!

Comment: In general, using `[[` to extract items from lists is more flexible and useful, particularly when dealing with other variables. `$` is convenient mainly when working interactively merely to save typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the models are stored in the list `mods`, you can access the "best model" by using the index of `which.min(list.AIC)`:

```
list.AIC <- sapply(mods, AIC)
best.mod <- mods[which.min(list.AIC)]
best.mod[[1]]
```